# Python 3: write string list to csv file

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I have found several answers (encoding, decoding...) online, but I still don't get what to do.

I have a list called abc.

```
abc = ['sentence1','-1','sentence2','1','sentence3','0'...]
```

Now I would like to store this list in a CSV file, the following way:
sentence1, -1
sentence2, 1
sentence3, 0

I know that the format of my abc list probably isn't how it should to achieve this. I guess it should be a list of lists? But the major problem is actually that I have no clue how to write this to a CSV file, using Python 3. The only times it kinda worked, was when every character turned out to be separated by a comma.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `join` to create a new list and then write to `csv` :

```
abc=['sentence1', '-1', 'sentence2', '1', 'sentence3', '0', 'sentence4']

new=[(abc[0],)]+[(''.join(i),) for i in zip(abc[1::2],abc[2::2])]

import csv
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    a.writerows(new)
```

result :

```
sentence1
-1sentence2
1sentence3
0sentence4
```

Comment: I tried your method and it worked! Only problem now is that, when I open the CSV file, there is a "blank" line in between every line of text. Any idea how to get rid of those?

Comment: @thesisstudent as you are using python 3! use ` newline=''` in your `open` function

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) is the documentation to work with files, and CSV is basically the same thing as txt, the difference is that you should use commas to separate the columns and new lines to rows.

In your example you could do this (or iterate over a loop):

```
formated_to_csv = abc[0]+','+abc[1]+','+abc[2]+','+abc[3]...
```

the value of *formated_to_csv* would be 'sentence1,-1,sentence2,1,sentence3,0'.. note that this is a single string, so it will generate a single row, and then write the *formated_to_csv* as text in the csv file :

```
f.write(formated_to_csv)
```

To put all sentences on the first column and all the numbers on the second column it would be better to have a list of lists :

```
abc = [['sentence1','-1'],['sentence2','1'],['sentence3','0']...]

for row in abc:
   f.write(row[0]+','+row[1])
```

The "conversion" to table will be done by excel, calc or whatever program that you use to read spreadsheets.